# Two div next each other next paragraph under the heighest div

Tags: html, css

I have two div next each other, like bootstrap Content 1 Longer and more line Content 2 Shorter and less line

And I would like if the new paragraph will be under the longer column.

What need for this?

Comment: This is extremely vague. The least you could do is show us your code and maybe provide a live example

Comment: Could you add your html & css code to the question? And maybe a visual representation of what exactly you want... That'll help :)